# How to Upload a Video File to S3 via a presigned url using JMeter for Performance Testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-s3, jmeter, boto3

So I'm currently working on an application that allows users to upload video files to an S3 bucket using presigned URLs. As part of the performance testing phase, I need to simulate this video file upload process using JMeter. Could anyone guide me on how exactly to configure JMeter to accomplish this ?

If anyone has a sample JMeter script for uploading video files to S3, it would be a great starting point for me. I could then modify it to suit my specific use case.

If it's not possible or too complex to achieve this directly with JMeter, could anyone recommend me any alternative tools ?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant configuration of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler would be something like:

[image]

More information:

- [S3 - PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html)
- [Uploading objects with presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

In general if you're capable of performing the upload you can just record the event using your browser (or [other application](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/desktop-performance-testing)) and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the file to JMeter's "bin" folder before uploading it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !! The last point about placing the video file into JMeter's bin folder was super useful as that's the step my colleague was missing in getting the upload process to function